# What is the easiest way to find the number of isomorphic subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

> Find the number of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{100}\times\mathbb{Z}_{500}$ are isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}_{25}\times\mathbb{Z}_{25}$.

Using the order of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{100}\times\mathbb{Z}_{500}$, it  was so tedious work for me.

Is there an another way to solve the above problem?

Comment: It is not tedious at all. There is just one such subgroup and it consists of all elements whose order divides $25$.